# I have wordpress mu and it has around 32000 tables

Tags: wordpress

I want to reduce the number of tables somehow because the performance of my datbaase server is reduced drastically due to it.

Comment: increase the temporary tables size and that should increase the performance? btw. what is the table size right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

increase the temp table size to 512mb